# How to convert from char arr[4][50] to char **arr

Tags: arrays, char

```
char f[4][50];
 for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
    cin>>f[j];
    Courses[i].setFields((char**)&f);
    file.write((char*)(Courses[i].getFeild()),50);
    }
```

this piece of code gives run time error any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared f as

char f[4][50];

So essentially,  f is a pointer to a pointer to the first character to the first string in an array. So you don't need an ampersand before f in:

```
Courses[i].setFields((char**)f)
```

Comment: it gives the same error the program doesn't accept any entering value and just closed